# Python - Count number of alphabets only in a string ignoring case

Tags: python, string

I am trying to find the number of occurrences of each alphabet in a string ignoring case,spaces and also special characters. What is the best way to do this.

EG:

```
i/p: ABCccCDde :)! f

o/p: A=1, B=1, C=4, D=2, E=1
```

Ive tried

```
abc = Counter(line.rstrip('\n'))
```

and also `defaultdict` but they dont ignore case. Also I need to weed out the special characters without spending too much time

Comment: define 'special character' .. in other words, do you only want alphanumeric characters?

Comment: Only alphabets and a couple times of each

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
>>> abc = 'ABCccCDde :)! f'
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(c for c in abc.upper() if c.isalpha())
Counter({'C': 4, 'D': 2, 'A': 1, 'B': 1, 'E': 1, 'F': 1})
```